# Spring.Net - How to get a data set back from MS SQL DB?

Tags: c#, spring.net

I want to use spring.net to call a stored procedure in MS SQL DB that does the following:

```
Select Name, Address From EmployeeTable where id=@ID
Select Count(*) From EmployeeTable where id=@ID
```

I then want to create List from first data set and int total from the second result set.

I don't want to create two stored procedures to do this and have to use one stored procedure because the logic written above is simplified.

I am aware of using IRowMapper but that will only map Employee class to the first result set and not the other one.
Can Spring.Net work with multiple result sets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This post in the spring.net forums addresses both this situation as well as a few other more advanced concepts in using the RowMapper infrastructure to handle interacting with sprocs:

http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?4581-Multiple-result-sets-from-StoredProcedure

Comment: what about result set extractor?